# What's the difference between variable length array and dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c

```
int a[n];
```

vs

```
int * a;
a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Could anyone explain pro and cons of both method respectively? (efficiency, security etc)

Comment: You cannot return a VLA to the caller; you can return malloced memory.

Comment: A VLA is limited by the stack size; malloced memory by the heap size, which is generally (much) larger than the stack size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is the VLA declaration introduces a new Variably Modified (VM) type and that the object has automatic storage, the `malloc()` variant has dynamic storage.

The code:

```
int a[n];
```

is seen by compiler as:

```
int T_elems = n;
typedef int T[T_elems];
T a;
```

As result array `a` has automatic storage and it is allocated on stack on modern systems. Automatic means that the object's memory is released when leaving the scope were the objects was introduced.

```
int *b;
{
   int a[n];
   // `a` is valid
   b = a;
}
// resources pointed by `b` are released
```

On the other hand the second snippet:

```
int * a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Creates a pointer to `int` and assign an dynamically allocated object to it. The objects resources are valid even though scope of `a` has ended. The memory is valid until release with `free()`.

```
int *b;
{
   int * a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   b = a;
}
// resources pointed by `b` are valid!
free(b);
// memory is no longer valid
```

There is a common misconception that VLA are always allocated on stack.
VLAs can be allocated on heap via pointer to arrays:

```
int (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[n]));
```

## Summary:

1. VLAs (and VM types)

Pros:

- simple allotaction of automatic VLAs
- "always" succeeds (behavior on failure in undefined by C standard)
- allocation is very fast (slightly slower than fixed arrays)
- no risk of leaks for automatic VLAs
- can have dynamic storage (via pointers to VLA)
- very convenient for multidimensional arrays
- carry its size thus `sizeof a` returns `n * sizeof int`

Cons:

- automatic VLAs can easily overflow stack
- VM types cannot be defined at file scope (cannot be returned)
- VM types cannot be used as struct members
- become optional feature since C11
- operand of `sizeof` of VLA type is evaluated
- automatic VLAs cannot be resized

2. Dynamic 1D array.

Pros:

- supported by all C standards
- can be any size, no stack limit
- indicates if allocation is successful, however on modern OS `malloc()` reserved address space. OS give little guarantee that the *memory* is reserrved
- can be resized with `realloc()`

Cons:

- more verbose syntax
- must check if successful
- allocations are slower than any stack-based allocations
- memory must be released with `free()` to avoid leaks
- do not carry size, one must keep size of array

---

The same data organized as a table:

|  | Automatic VLA | `malloc` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Syntax | Simple | More verbose |
| Behavior on error | Stack overflow | `NULL` |
| Error handling | Impossible: behavior on failure is undefined | Must check `malloc`'s return value |
| Maximal size | Stack size | Heap size (larger than stack) |
| Speed | Very fast (slightly slower than fixed arrays) | Slower than any stack-based allocation |
| Deallocation | Automatic; no risk of leaks | Memory must be released with free() to avoid leaks |
| Array size support | Yes, by `sizeof` | No, programmer must store explicitly |
| Can return it? | No | Yes |
| Can put in `struct`? | No | Yes |
| Portability | C99, Became optional feature since C11 | Supported by all C standards |
| Supports resizing? | No | Yes, by `realloc` |
| Multi-dimensional | Simple syntax | Possibly confusing syntax |

Comment: I tried to organize the data in a table. Looks better, though I may have missed or misinterpreted some details.

Comment: @anatolyg, it looks very nice. It actually stays focus on what OP asked form "automatic VLAs" vs "malloc". I diverged a bit on general VM types

Answer (score 1):

VLAs behave (mostly) like any other `auto` variable - storage for them will automatically be released when you exit their enclosing scope.  Dynamic memory will not be released until you explicitly `free` it.

VLAs are great when you need some temporary working storage that doesn’t need to be too big or hang around beyond the lifetime of its enclosing function.  Like fixed-length local arrays, they cannot be arbitrarily large.  Despite the name, variable-length arrays cannot be resized once they are defined - the "variable" in variable-length simply means that their size can be different each time it is instantiated.

You’d use dynamic memory when you don’t know until runtime how much memory you need and the allocated object has to live outside the lifetime of any specific function, or needs to be very large, or needs to be resizable (using `realloc`).